# 90s/early 2000s sci-fi horror movie scene

Tags: story-identification, horror

There was this movie I watched as a child with my parents, and I can remember one specific scene that scared the daylights out of me.

The scene was referring this woman who I think died early on in the movie. It was a team of people watching a short video that a hacker or hacker group made to mocked this woman.

The original video was of said woman smiling and dancing in a white dress and there were two videos. The first edited video was of the woman crawling out of a bathtub, but it was clear that it was edited as the woman's limbs were moving rigidly, one at a time, similar to how early Flash/stick figure animations were made. It showed her getting out of the bathtub with her arms out in front of her, like a zombie.

The second edited video was that of the original clip, but the original audio cutting off halfway and some sort of skull/skeleton emerging from the woman? Again, it wasn't smoothly made and was accompanied by some sort of screaming noise. I can't remember this scene as much as I can the first one.

I've been racking my brain trying to find out the name of the movie. My parents said that the movie was Alien or Aliens or something like that but we watched another movie before that so they were probably confused as to which one I was asking the name of.

I cannot remember anything else from the movie apart from this specific scene.

Comment: I can't see anything in this that is science fictional or fantastical. If I'm reading it correctly it's just about a couple of videos that were edited. If so this isn't really on topic. Could you clarify, what, if anything, was science fictional or fantastical about this? Preferably with an [edit] to the question.

Comment: You're right, it's too broad. I'll ask this somewhere else.

Comment: It's not too broad (that has a specific meaning here) but it doesn't seem like it's on topic. However, you do say it's a horror movie which means it probably is on topic but you'd need to clarify that a bit.

Comment: It's [The Ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ring_(2002_film)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a similar shot in “Copycat” which is a thriller starring Sigourney Weaver. The killer sends the Police a video file with a clip of his intended victim dancing at a music festival (possibly at Golden Gate Park). Her face morphs into a skull and it screams. The effects are primitive (this was 1990 I think?) but that adds to the creepiness.

Comment: The skeleton/skull clip can be seen at https://youtu.be/5Pp64srMAH4?t=57

Comment: This is it! Thank you!

Comment: Awesome!  You know come to think of it (confirmation bias anyone??? :) ) the bathtub graphic is also definitely in there too.